# List groups that have members from a specific OU in ActiveDirectory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have an OU called "InactiveUsers", to which I move all users that will be inactivated in my organization.
And I'm trying to list all the groups in my domain, having at least one user OU (InactiveUsers) as a member.

But do not know how to do, someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: -1 What have you tried? Which module are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "<OU=InactiveUsers,etc..>" | Select -ExpandProperty Memberof | select -Unique | sort
```

That's the basic idea using the MS-provided AD Module.